# C++ Primer (5th Edition) and C++14

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, optimization, c++14

I've recently bought the book [C++ Primer (5th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) and I've noticed that the book is updated to the C++11 version and not to the latest C++14.
Is there  anything that I need to do different to adapt myself to the new C++14?

I'm afraid that I'll learn things in the book that are no longer relevant, or not in the most efficient way, because of the differences between the versions and the additions to the C++14.  If you could let me know if there is anything that I need to do differently to make my code more aesthetic or efficient, I would appreciate it.

Comment: C++14's changes from C++11 are largely additive, so no, you won't learn anything irrelevant.

Comment: It should be easy enough to go through a list of C++14 features after.

Comment: Note that the book dates from August 2012; it is not unreasonable that it does not cover C++14.

Answer (score 7):

C++14 is a so-called "minor update" to C++11. C++14 adds to C++11 and allows you to take a few *more* shortcuts and to write *more* like a script kiddie getting started with PHP.

There will be some minor gaps in your knowledge if you learn from a C++11 book, but nothing serious. There were no paradigm shifts in the interim, nothing substantial was removed, and you won't be left behind.

For any code usage that doesn't quite match up, you may simply refer to [a decent reference](http://cppreference.com). Again, for the most part, these are really very minor changes.

Comment: Upvoted especially for *a script kiddie getting started with PHP*. Brilliant description of new `auto`s in lambdas and returns :)